# Is there any way to allocate more RAM in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, memory, ram, allocation

I started working on a game recently, and I already coded the 'Resource-Loading-Procedur', which loads all textures, sounds, etc. into the memory. It works perfectly fine with the current 10 to 15 files, but after testing with many more files I got an `OutOfMemoryException`, because the program can only use 2GB RAM max.

I did a little workaround by opening every file in a FileStream and storing these FileStreams in a list, but this will cause Ingame-Loading to be slower because I have to load every single texture which is being used.

I would appreciate any answers!

Regards,
Mika.

Comment: Project > Properties > Compile tab.  Change the Target CPU to AnyCPU, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox if you see it.  That's the quick way.  Otherwise splitting your game up into levels and only loading the resources that the level requires is surely a technique you've seen used before.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and it works. It's really that simple? xD Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Well, It is not possible to allocate memory in VB.NET.
The default is 2048MB of memory to allocate.
If you want to allocate memory in C# Use:

malloc(16384)

This code will allocate 16MB in memory

Comment: C# has memory management with garbage collection: there is no malloc.